# How to prevent Excel from automatically applying word wrap to cell

Tags: excel, format

I noticed that when I'm typing text into a cell that has word wrap **off**, if the text exceeds the width of the cell, Excel automatically turns word wrap **on**.

I don't think it happens all the time, and I haven't investigated exactly the conditions, but I found it annoying enough that I wrote a simple macro to solve the problem.

But if there's another approach, I'd be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

My macro uses the Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Replace <...> with an actual condition if desired.
If <target cell is one I want to keep unwrapped> Then
    Target.WrapText = False
End If

End Sub
```

The `If` statement is optional. I use it to restrict the macro to working in a particular column.

You could also limit it to Targets that are single cell ranges, but it didn't seem necessary in my situation.